# Start activity from an Edittextpreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to start an activity from an Edittextpreference. When the user tries to tap on it, or when just taping on the edittextpreference, it triggers the activity. Is that possible?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PreferenceActivity

```
EditTextPreference pref = (EditTextPreference)findPreference("setting_key");
pref.setIntent(new Intent(this, YourActivity.class));
```

[Description of setIntent(intent) from docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setIntent%28android.content.Intent%29)

Comment: That works :). And that's completely logicial ;). How I did not think about that :D ? Thanks :)

Comment: It does not work for me for some reason. I have the OnPreferenceClick implemented, which is passing the parameters for that pop-up activity. If I'm returning with true (processed) from onPreferenceClick - the standard EditTextPreference popup is shown. If I return with false. The custom intent works, but it shows the original intent first and returns to it after the custom activity exits. In other words both activities are popping up on my 2.1 target.